# How to get the difference in days(row wise) in power bi for each id per version

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate the difference between days (row wise) for each ID, each Iteration where the first record of each ID and each version is 0. I tried few code snippets, but didn't worked such as:

```
Calculated Time = 
VAR Index = Table[Version]
VAR Reference = Table[Id]
VAR Prevtime =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( Table[Date], TRUE () ),
        FILTER (Table, Table[Id] = Reference  && Table[Version]  = Index)
    )
RETURN
Table[Date] - Prevtime
```

Desired outcome:

```
ID  Version Date              Calculated time      Formula
12345   1   11/1/2018 8:08      0                   0
12345   1   11/16/2018 8:39     15.02152778         =C3-C2
12345   1   11/16/2018 13:29    0.201388889         =C4-C3
12345   1   11/16/2018 13:32    0.002083333 
12345   2   11/16/2018 8:39     0   
12345   2   11/26/2018 14:24    10.23958333 
12345   2   11/26/2018 14:24    0   
12345   3   11/16/2018 8:39     0   
12345   3   12/6/2018 12:13     20.14861111 
12345   3   12/6/2018 12:20     0.004861111
```

Any inputs are appreciated. Please let me know if i need to do some changes to the above code or if you can assist me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

[image]

It works like this:
`ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Version] )` returns the 'Table' table, filtered on the [ID] and [Version] of the current row. The CALCULATE funtion then calculates the biggest [Date] from that filtered table, that is smaller than [Date] in the current row.

The EARLIER function is used to go to the previous filtercontext, which is the rowcontext, to get the [Date] value form the current row.

So VAR prevTime is the previous [Date] with the same [ID] and [Version]. When no previous [Date] exists, prevTime is BLANK.

```
Calculated time =
VAR prevTime =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Version] ),
        'Table'[Date] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( prevTime ), BLANK (), 'Table'[Date] - prevTime )
```

Comment: Graag gedaan;-) Would you please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you?

Comment: But the data is not always sorted, as a result the calculated time gives wrong answers, can you please let me know how to correct those values ?

Comment: The order of the data should not be a problem. Can you give an example?